# Python: How to require an input to correspond with a previous input?

Tags: python, dictionary, input, syntax

all. Python newbie here.

Simply-put here is my basic idea:

I want to create a "Login" feature where people must input a valid username from a preset tuple.
Next, once a valid name is entered, they will be asked to enter the corresponding code name, which is saved to a dictionary. (I have a feeling that I am over-complicating this, or maybe the dictionary is the wrong idea entirely, so any advice on how to simplify would be great).

```
real_names = ("JD", "JM" "JC")
player_ids = {"JD":"Arrow","JM":"Bullet","JC":"Blade"}

while True:
    # user must input a name from the real_names tuple
    name = input("User unidentified. Please input your name: ")
    # if username is not in tuple, rerun script
    if not name in real_names:
        print("Invalid username detected")
        continue
    print(f"Positive ID! Welcome, {name}")
    break
```

The above code works just fine. But next, I want to make a new input that requires the player ID to match the previously input name. In Pseudo-code, something like this:

```
# While True Loop:
     id = input("Please confirm user Code Name: ")
     #ID must correspond to keyword in dictionary
     if ID value does not match username Keyword:
          print("Invalid ID")
          continue
     print("Identity confirmed!")
     break
```

Am I on the right path? If so, how would I syntax the second part? If the dictionary is the wrong idea entirely, please provide a good alternative. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`player_ids[name]` is the value you're looking for.  So, you want something like this:

```
if id != player_ids[name]:
    print("invalid ID")
```

Also, the dictionary already keeps track of player names, so you don't need the `real_names` tuple.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

This previous answer works perfect, because you are looking up the value based on the key from a dictionary. Finally, one little tip, it's always good practice to avoid naming variables after reserved variables and keywords, that is to say, use another variable name just in case you are going to use to use the `id()` function again in the program.